# Edit CSS/LESS problems

Tags: magento2, css, less

so I would like to change this css

```
  .navigation,
  .breadcrumbs,
  .page-header .header.panel,
  .header.content,
  .footer.content,
  .page-wrapper > .widget,
  .page-wrapper > .page-bottom,
  .block.category.event,
  .top-container,
  .page-main {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 1280px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    width: auto;
  }
```

so it does not appy to .page-main

```
  .navigation,
  .breadcrumbs,
  .page-header .header.panel,
  .header.content,
  .footer.content,
  .page-wrapper > .widget,
  .page-wrapper > .page-bottom,
  .block.category.event,
  .top-container{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 1280px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    width: auto;
  }
```

i get that I can change the variables for example @layout__max-width with my _theme.less but where does it say for which classes those styles apply?

Also I still refuse to believe that this is really the best way to customize my css. Do I really have to search 20 minutes trough all those .less files just to find some variable so i can override it with my _theme.less file.

Answer (score 2):

- To discover easier you can set the developer mode and use this method on the DevDocs to debug LESS:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html

- Use an IDE (e.g. PHPStorm) with support for LESS to CLICK + ALT on the variable to find out the location.
- You can use to check the variables and patterns on the Magento UI library here:

https://magebr.github.io/Magento-2-UI-library/index.html